# Encoding Failed Error in Wistia

Tags: php, curl, wistia

I am trying to upload videos to Wistia. The video was uploaded successfully. But the problem is that, when I play the video showing Error Message like **Encoding Failed Error.** Here I have shared my code for reference.

### Code :

```
public function video_upload($filePath,$fileName){

$tempuploaddir = "img/temp/";
if (!file_exists($tempuploaddir)) {
mkdir($tempuploaddir, 0777, true);
chmod($tempuploaddir, 0777);
}

move_uploaded_file($filePath,$loc=$tempuploaddir.$fileName);
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? 'https' : 'http';
$serverURL = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->request->webroot;
$urlPath= $serverURL.'webroot/'.$loc;

$data = array(
'api_password' => '0fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf5',
'url' => $urlPath
);

$chss = curl_init('https://upload.wistia.com');
curl_setopt_array($chss, array(
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
));

$KReresponse = curl_exec($chss);

$KReresponseData = json_decode($KReresponse, TRUE);
unlink($tempuploaddir.$fileName);
echo("Response:");
print_r($KReresponseData);

}
```

**Error Msg :**
[Click Here to view the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTxmf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, finally I resolved my error. By using cURL file object method.

```
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile('cats.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');

// Assign POST data
$data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Execute the handle
curl_exec($ch);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php